# Only can upload 1 file to s3 bucket but not other files using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files inside a folder to a S3 bucket but I cannot seem to upload all files. Here is my code:

```
    try:
        for folder in os.listdir('raw_data/'):
            for files in os.listdir(f'raw_data/{folder}'):
                if folder == 'malay':
                    upload_file_bucket = 'book-reviews-analysis'
                    upload_file_key = 'malay/' + str(files)
                    client.upload_file(files, upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key)
                    logger.info('--DONE UPLOADING FILE TO BUCKET--')
                elif folder == 'english':
                    upload_file_bucket='book-reviews-analysis'
                    upload_file_key='english/' + str(files)
                    client.upload_file(files,upload_file_bucket,upload_file_key)
                    logger.info('--DONE UPLOADING FILE TO BUCKET--')
    except ClientError as e:
            print(e)
            logger.error(e)
```

The weird thing is that it does upload a file in the english folder but not in the 'malay' folder. I got the following error and I am very certain that the file I want to upload is in that folder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/personal project/Book review analysis/book_reviews_analysis/pipeline.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/personal project/Book review analysis/book_reviews_analysis/pipeline.py", line 61, in main
    upload_to_s3()
  File "D:/personal project/Book review analysis/book_reviews_analysis/pipeline.py", line 42, in upload_to_s3
    client.upload_file(files, upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key)
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 148, in upload_file
    callback=Callback,
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py", line 288, in upload_file
    future.result()
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 269, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\upload.py", line 585, in _submit
    upload_input_manager.provide_transfer_size(transfer_future)
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\upload.py", line 244, in provide_transfer_size
    self._osutil.get_file_size(transfer_future.meta.call_args.fileobj)
  File "D:\personal project\Book review analysis\book_reviews_analysis\env\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line 247, in get_file_size
    return os.path.getsize(filename)
  File "C:\Users\aliff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'politik_untuk_pemula.CSV'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: The issue that I noticed in ```client.upload_file(files,upload_file_bucket,upload_file_key)``` is that ```files``` doesn't have the path.   The system is looking for the file in the current directory.  You need to specify the path as well.   i.e. ```os.path.join('raw_data', files)```.

Comment: @ewokx you are right on the part where `files`  doesn't have the path. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

As @ewokx mentioned in their comment:

> `files` doesn't have the path.

That said, try using `pathlib.Path`, like so:

```py
from pathlib import Path

src_dir = Path("raw_data")
files_coll = src_dir.glob("*/*")
for one_file in files_coll:
    folder = one_file.parent.name
    if folder == "malay":
        upload_file_bucket = 'book-reviews-analysis'
        upload_file_key = 'malay/' + str(one_file.name)
        # Check boto3 documentation; if upload_file() accepts Path-like object, then no need for str()
        client.upload_file(str(one_file), upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key)
        logger.info('--DONE UPLOADING FILE TO BUCKET--')
    elif folder == "english":
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried using `Path` before somehow but it didn't work. But this solution does provide the full path to `upload_file`.